# How to fetch my app's events from calendar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have added events to calendar using EventKit and I can fetch all events from calendar, but I need only my app's event from calendar. So now my question is, how can I fetch events which are related to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func getEvents() -> [EKEvent] {
    var allEvents: [EKEvent] = []

    // calendars
    let calendars = self.eventStore.calendars(for: .event)

    // iterate over all selected calendars
    for (_, calendar) in calendars.enumerated() where isCalendarSelected(calendar.calendarIdentifier) {

        // predicate for today (start to end)
        let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: self.initialDates.first!, end: self.initialDates.last!, calendars: [calendar])

        let matchingEvents = self.eventStore.events(matching: predicate)

        // iterate through events
        for event in matchingEvents {
            allEvents.append(event)
        }
    }

    return allEvents
}
```

this code will gvie you all events and then you have to filter it by title or something which can be identify that this event is from your app :)